# How do I register a modules' cronjob

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, cron

## Synopsis

First of all I wish to express how a third-party extension to list the crobjobs is not what I am looking for, I shall omit my opinion for how Magento handles cronjobs.

My problem is when I query the database `SELECT * FROM cron_schedule;` my modules cron is not listed there, thus I can only assume my cron configuration is wrong, but so far I've not found any resources to help.

## Cron set-up

My cron has been set-up on the server to run every 5 minutes (this is where I dislike Magento abstracting cronjobs).

> crontab -e
>
> */5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/site/public_html/cron.sh > /dev/null &2>1

For the exercise of getting my cron to run, I am running the cron from the command line `$ /bin/sh cron.sh` - Inside the `cron_schedule` I see that `executed_at` is updated but not for my cronjob but an existing modules cron.

## Snippet

**config.xml**

```
<config>

    ...

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <myvendor_mymodule>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>myvendor_mymodule/cron::someMethod</model>
                </run>
            </myvendor_mymodule>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Myvendor/Mymodule/Model/Cron.php**

```
class Myvendor_Mymodule_Model_Cron
{
    //public static function someMethod() #= no luck either
    public function someMethod()
    {
        Mage::log('test', null, 'hello.log');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cron_schedule` tables contains a list of scheduled cronjobs, including the time they've been added to the schedule, the scheduled exectution time, the state, and, when done, the time they've finished.

The table is populated when the `cron.sh` script is run (should run every 5 minutes via the system cronjob (crontab -e -u )). The first call will populate the table and later work off the queue. You can think of the `cron_schedule` table as a job-queue where the exection-times are based on your `config.xml`.

Magento will schedule the crons automatically, so you don't need to take care of it. Make sure you've refreshed the config-cache after adding the cronjob and the `cron.sh` runs periodically.
Also usually it's better to run `cron.sh` instead of `cron.php` because in the new versions Magento uses different run modes and calls the `cron.php` with the appropriate configuration, umask, path, etc. automatically.

This extension might be interesting for you: https://github.com/AOEmedia/Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: @Marius - Personally I dislike the way Magento has abstracted `crontab`.  Linux has implemented `crontab` in a simple and elegant manner, imo Magento has just complicated the process by using databases and forking background processes then routing stout/stderr to `/dev/null`.  As a server administrator myself I dislike my control being taken from me.

Comment: I take that back - problem hasn't been solved >.> my module cron still is not appearing the `cron_schedule` ARGH!

Comment: Totally agreed. One of the "features" in Magento that could have been easier. Back to your Problem: If you install Aoe_Scheduler can you see the cronjob in the list? And is the module active anyway (app/etc/modules/Myvendor_Mymodule.xml)? Maybe the issue is not the cron at all?

Comment: @thebod - OK, I will have ponder and see.  It's strange that when I run the cron my task doesn't get added to the `cron_schedule` table, which is why I thought it was the `config.xml` syntax.  My question is what does `AOE_Scheduler` do that `SELECT * FROM cron_schedule` doesn't?

Comment: Aoe_Scheduler also reads the configuration to show a list of available cronjobs. You can enable/disable them there, see a timeline with execution times, etc...

Comment: @thebod - So I installed this module and I will give credit where it is due.  It loaded my cron and I was able to run my cron from within the Admin CP.  My question now is; **Why do I need this module to make crons work?**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `cron.php` or `cron.sh` is set to run regularly in Linux cron file.

From [magento cron manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

> The cron.php file located in the Magento root will need to be run
>   periodically, for example every 15 minutes. Basically, this script
>   will check if it needs to run any tasks, and if it needs to schedule
>   any future tasks.

**Update**

The problem is that `<cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>` means Daily at midnight. But magento is not putting tasks into cron_schedule immediately. Only if execution time is very close. Try to change cron_expr to `<cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>`. And you should see the difference.

Comment: I updated my question to include the crontab schedule for clarity.  Regardless, I am running the cron.sh from the terminal directly, I can see `executed_at` being updated but no new cron in my list.

Comment: Set cron_expr to  * * * * *. And check if your job was executed.

Comment: That's not going to change anything because I am running `cron.sh` on the command line. I know my crontab is set-up correctly, but I'm not sure about my `config.xml` syntax.

Comment: your config.xml syntax is correct.

Comment: Okay, that good.  So here's the process - I run `bin/sh cron.sh` which forks `cron.php -- options` in the background.  Magento then checks for crons it needs to run from `cron_schedule`.  **How do I register my cron task into the `cron_schedule` table using that `config.xml`?**

Comment: The problem is that `<cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>` means `Daily at midnight`. But magento is not putting tasks into `cron_schedule` immediately. Only if execution time is very close. Try to change `cron_expr` to `<cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>`. And you should see the difference.

Comment: You should do that only to make sure that everything works after you will set your changes back.

Comment: And do not forget to clear cache.