# how to Set up database values to crontab jobs in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, cron

in my `config.xml` file have `crontab`

```
.....
    <crontab>
            <jobs>
                <autoreplenish_test>
                    <schedule>
                        <config_path>how to set up here database values</config_path>
                    </schedule>
                    <run>
                        <model>autoreplenish/replenish::run</model>
                    </run>
                </autoreplenish_test>
            </jobs>
        </crontab>
...
```

Comment: [This answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/how-do-i-register-a-modules-cronjob) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you out

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job
http://blog.belvg.com/magento-certified-developer-exam-setting-up-a-cron-job.html

Comment: it's better to add specified code because link may not be worked in future. Please add explain answer with code.

Comment: You are correct, but in my opinoin it's not nice to copy some one else's work and put it here :) feel free to edit my answer..

Comment: Actually my concern is that, you follow the correct code format here, not just copy or paste so that asking person get proper solution of his/her problem. it feel honest to copy or paste any one code but it also feel much good to find some way and modified it to help other one person. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
        <crontab>
            <jobs>
                <autoreplenish_test>
                    <schedule>
                        <config_path>customsection/cronfield/cron_settings</config_path>
                    </schedule>
                    <run>
                        <model>autoreplenish/replenish::run</model>
                    </run>
                </autoreplenish_test>
            </jobs>
        </crontab>
```

this has worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get this to work is to rewrite the `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule`

```
<models>
    <your_module>
        <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
    </your_module>
    <cron>
        <rewrite>
            <schedule>Your_Module_Model_Schedule</schedule>
        </rewrite>
    </cron>
</models>
```

Then you would need to rewrite the function `setCronExpr` and update is so it tries to load the value from the database first and then defaults to the normal behaviour.

**Note: You will have to check your xml back to `cron_expr` and what ever you store in the database should be a valid cron expression**

See [this question and answer combo](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19480/cron-job-asterisk-meaning/19482#19482) for what is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing cron time interval on you code< i have set cron  will run every  30mins interval

```
<cron_expr>30 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

more details http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

```
<crontab>
<jobs>
<autoreplenish_test>
<schedule><cron_expr>30 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
<run><model>autoreplenish/replenish::run</model></run>
</autoreplenish_test>
</jobs>
</crontab>
```